# Appium service builder not starting service

Tags: java, android, appium

I am able to start the appium server manually via terminal using command `"appium --use-plugins execute-driver"`

When I try to start appium service programtically, I am getting an error of "Unrecognized arguments: --plugins execute-driver"
If I remove the withArgument property then i get error "Appium spawn npm ENOENT"

Below is my code:

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
.usingDriverExecutable(new File("//Users//ABC//.nvm//versions//node//v19.2.0//bin//node"))
.withAppiumJS(new File("//Users//ABC//.nvm//versions//node//v19.2.0//lib/node_modules//appium//build//lib//main.js"))
.withArgument(() ->"--use-plugins", "execute-driver")
.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).build();
        
        service.start();
        
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName("sampleDevice");
        options.setApp("//Users//ABC//Documents//appiumSampleProject//src//test//java//resources//Demos-debug.apk");

        
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"),options);
```

Can some one help with possible resolution for above problem

Answer (score 0):

The argument that you use in the terminal is different from the one you send programmatically: --plugins vs. --use-plugins.

```
.withArgument(() ->"--use-plugins", "execute-driver")
```

Comment: yes, I corrected that but still stuck with error "appum spawn npm enonet"